# How to access iframe history.length

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser-history

I am trying to understand iframe history. I have created to pages A and B on a localhost server. Using an iframe I load page A first then dynamically change the iframe src to page B. Should this mean `history.length`=2 as two different URLs visited? It does when trying without iframes. However, by using iframes I am only getting the value 1 being returned?

```
<body>
<div>
    <iframe src='/pageA.php' id='myframe' onload='checkHistory()' ></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
    function checkHistory() 
    {
            document.getElementById('myframe').src='/pageB.php';
            alert("Number of URLs in history list: " + history.length);
    }
</script>
```

Am I accessing the history.lenght value for the iframe correctly or does the iframe have to be accessed like `document.getElementById('myframe').history.length` rather than the generic `history.length` property?

This has puzzled me. I have tried storing the `history.length` value before opening page B and comparing the values but still no luck. There must be a way that iframes store history of pages visited inside same as a browser tab window does?

Answer (score -3):

Each `iframe` exists as its own entity:  a window and document in its own right.  The iframe's history is not tied to the parent's history; pages loaded in the iframe do not count toward the parent's history.  You can access the iframe's own history via:

```
document.getElementById("myframe").contentWindow.history.length
```

(This assumes your iframe is loaded from the same domain as the parent, as your example indicates.)

Comment: what about if the iframe's content is from other domain ?

Comment: this is incorrect. navigation within the iframe does add to the parent's history.length value and clicking back will first navigate back in the iframe's history if the most recent navigation was within the frame. you are correct that the details of the history are obscured, however.